# Safari has a problem displaying certain images

Tags: macos, safari, web-browsing

Safari does not display certain images properly.

The latest example is https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEoIr.jpg which is perfectly loadable in firefox.

In Safari however the picture is displayed properly while it is loading/as long as it is only partially loaded. When it should display the whole picture all I get is black or white box. It can be clicked to zoom in though.

### Safari

[image: Safari 7.0.3]

### Firefox

[image: Firefox]

I've had the same problem once before. That time I found this thread: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3796427

and was able to get it working by deleting:

```
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
```

I've tried that this time as well, but the picture is still failing.

The system is updated. My version of Safari is 7.0.3 (9537.75.14). The operating system is  OS X 10.9.2 (13C1021).

What can I do to get the browser working again?

EDIT:

I've tried removing all extensions from the browser.
[image: Extensions]

I only had [Reddit enhancement suite](http://redditenhancementsuite.com) installed before cleaning.

EDIT2: problem persists after updating to Safari Version 7.1 (9537.85.10.17.1)

EDIT3: Problem solved in Safari Version 8.0 (10600.1.25)!

Comment: Same system setup. Link works in my safari. (no changes done to the link) But does not show the image bordered in black

Comment: Do you have any extension on that could be interfering

Comment: I had reddit enhancement suite installed as my only extension. Removing that made no difference.

Comment: I' ve the same in 7.0.3 (9537.75.14) with all the icons in Facebook.

Comment: I have exactly same problem and still can not find how to fix this. I noticed, that black background shows only then progressive JPEG is loading. I use latest Mac OS X Maverics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to OSX 10.10 Yosemite today. It brought Safari Version 8.0 (10600.1.25).

I no longer have trouble opening the image! =)

Answer (score 3):

It does work on my MBA 10.9.2 Safari 7.0.3 ?

At the moment I do not know what is causing it on your computer.

Here are some initial findings:

That site has some bad formatting to begin with:

For example if you change the Margin to 3 instead of 0 the magnifier will no longer go outside of the image area, which is the first indication of a problem with that link.

```
<body style="margin: 3px;"><img style="-webkit-user-select: none; cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;" src="http://i.imgur.com/GqQchYM.jpg" width="166" height="222"></body>
```

<sup>The image is set to display in width=166 , height=222, while the Natural size is 3120x4160.</sup>

UPDATE:

Since It works on my computer I would say it is your specific Safari installation.

We could go in to trying to repair your Safari (I do not know a quick way to do it)!?, but to be honest, if you have that problem on a bigger scale, I would recommend to reInstall Safari. Unfortunately that means reInstalling Mavericks. So the choice is yours.

Comment: My Safari shows the title as GqQchYM.jpg 3,120x4 160 pixel

Comment: As a test I just set my number separator grouping in  format in Language & region to a 'space' and reloaded the safari page. I got the space in the title. So that all that is.

Comment: great find, so it is not that ?

Answer (score 1):

Trying it as a different user or as a newly-created user account should quickly tell you if it's a bug in your version of Safari or a system-wide corruption vs. a cache or preference issue.

Since Safari 7.0.4 is out, you might also try updating.

Comment: Same error in Safari 7.0.4.

Comment: Logged in as my wife the picture still displays wrong.

Comment: Created a new user - the picture still won't load.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug that manifests itself when using Intel integrated graphics.  Using [gfxCardStatus](https://gfx.io) to force the use of the discrete video card works around the problem.